# click events not firing on inner divs

Tags: jquery, html, css

If I take the .thumbnail divs outside of the #thumbhider and #thumbcontent divs then the click events work fine and as expected. Currently they do not.

URL: http://www.samcoles.co.uk/dustbowl/guitars.php

I'm guessing this is something to do with the overflow:hidden on the containing div? How can I work around this?

**the javascript:**

```
//this is within $(document).ready function
$(".thumbnail").click(function () {

    var IMAGE_DIR = "images/guitars/";
    var img = $(this).find("img").attr("alt");
    $("#mainphoto").attr("src", IMAGE_DIR + img);
    if(captions) {
        $("#imgcaption").text(captions[img]);
    }
});
```

**the css:**

```
div.thumbnail { background-color: #000000; padding: 1px; float: left; width: 69px; height: 69px; cursor: pointer; }
div#thumbhider { width: 673px; height: 70px; overflow: hidden; margin: 0 auto; margin-top: 19px; position: relative; }
div.thumbcontent { height: 70px; background-color: #00ff00; width: 0 auto; display: inline; position: relative; }
```

**the html:**

```
<div id="thumbhider">
        <div class="thumbcontent">
            <div style="margin-right:15px;" class="thumbnail"><img alt="1.png" src="thumber.php?img=images/guitars/1.png&amp;h=69&amp;w=69"></div>
            <div style="margin-right:15px;" class="thumbnail"><img alt="10.png" src="thumber.php?img=images/guitars/10.png&amp;h=69&amp;w=69"></div>

            <!--etc....-->

            <div style="clear:both;"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: BTW your site is a mess of positioned elements. Hard to debug...

Comment: I am doing it as a favour. Front-end web dev isn't really my thing!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove `position:relative` from `div.thumbcontent`

```
div.thumbcontent {
    height: 70px;
    background-color: lime;
    width: 0 auto;
    display: inline;
    /*position:relative*/
}
```

Comment: You're welcome. This error was obvious and easy to fix. You've set `cursor:pointer` to your `.thumbnail` elements but nothing happens on mouseover. So it could not be the js CLICK event or an overflow issue.